# Numpy: Indexing of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Given the following example

```
d = array([[1, 2, 3],
           [1, 2, 3],
           [1, 3, 3],
           [4, 4, 4],
           [5, 5, 5]
          ])
```

To get the sub-array containing `1` in the first column:

```
d[ d[:,0] == 1 ]

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 3, 3]])
```

How to get (without loops) the sub-array containing `1` and `5`? Shouldn't be something like

```
d[ d[:,0] == [1,5] ]  #   ---> array([1, 2, 3])
```

which does not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Method #1: use bitwise or `|` to combine the conditions:

```
>>> d
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5]])
>>> (d[:,0] == 1) | (d[:,0] == 5)
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> d[(d[:,0] == 1) | (d[:,0] == 5)]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 3, 3],
       [5, 5, 5]])
```

Method #2: use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html), which is probably easier if there are a lot of values:

```
>>> np.in1d(d[:,0], [1, 5])
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> d[np.in1d(d[:,0], [1, 5])]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 3, 3],
       [5, 5, 5]])
```

Comment: the second solution is what I need. I was not aware of this in1d(). Thanks!